How to find domains that have IP address 142.251.211.234 defined, belonging to a google API?
I'm searching for domains that own IP addresses that I'm seeing traffic to in my GCP network, in order to configure a firewall rule for that specific domain.
For 142.251.211.234, I know it's a Google API because the VPC Flow Logs specify that the src_google_service is a "GOOGLE_API" (ref). The IP is also within the GCP ranges of google cloud services (ref).
Typically I can look in the DNS logs in logs explorer by filtering through logName="projects/<project_name>/logs/dns.googleapis.com%Fdns_queries" and this gives me my answer. But not for 142.251.211.234.
A reverse DNS lookup such as dig -x <ip> seems to be quite useless for Google APIs. For example, 216.239.38.174 the reverse DNS query does not provide the domain:
$ dig -x 216.239.38.174

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> -x 216.239.38.174
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 8237
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;174.38.239.216.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
38.239.216.in-addr.arpa. 60 IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 679515077 900 900 1800 60

;; Query time: 36 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Sep 28 18:22:03 EDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 116

but IP address 216.239.38.174 belongs to: logging-alv.googleapis.com
$ dig logging.googleapis.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> logging.googleapis.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14750
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;logging.googleapis.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
logging.googleapis.com. 101 IN  CNAME   logging-alv.googleapis.com.
logging-alv.googleapis.com. 209 IN  A   216.239.34.174
logging-alv.googleapis.com. 209 IN  A   216.239.32.174
logging-alv.googleapis.com. 209 IN  A   216.239.38.174
logging-alv.googleapis.com. 209 IN  A   216.239.36.174

;; Query time: 17 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.1#53(192.168.2.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Sep 28 18:21:51 EDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 141


I'm not sure I understand your question... You start talking about 142.251.211.234 (which does have a reverse, which obviously belongs to Google, the forward of which points back to the same IP), and then you give us data about 216.239.38.174. If all you want to do is configure firewall rules, since you have the ranges, what is you actual question?

It is not mandatory to maintain reverse DNS records, so when there is no PTR record, DNS won’t help you to identify the user/owner of a particular IP-address.
Even when there is a reverse DNS record for that IP-address:
Many different FQDN hostnames can point to the same IP-address but the reverse DNS record for that IP can effectively only point to one FQDN ; so you can’t use reverse DNS to find a complete list of those hostnames.
Note that regardless DNS is not the most reliable way to identify the owner/maintainer of an IP-address. The owner of an IP-address range and the associated in-addr.arpa. zone can set up PTR records with any domain, including domains they don’t operate or own.
Only when both the reverse and forward DNS records match can a reverse DNS record be considered as a trusted and reliable source to identify the likely user of an IP-address.
Ownership of an IP-address can be determined via WHOIS but often that will show an ISP or other provider as the owner. You probably want to know the customer of the ISP and the current user of a particular IP-address. ISP’s only rarely update WHOIS with the details of their customers and the current user to whom the usage of that particular IP-address has been granted.

One way that you might answer this question (that doesn't work here) is to open a TLS connection to that IP address and see what certificate is served.
In this case, the server serves up a certificate for
subject=OU = "No SNI provided; please fix your client.", CN = invalid2.invalid

This suggests that this IP address can serve requests for a number of different hostnames, and relies on SNI to determine which hostname it is acting as in this instance.
If we make a request for, for example, www.google.com:
curl --connect-to www.google.com:443:142.251.211.234:443 https://www.google.com

we get what seems to be the standard Google search page. It responds with the relevant looking pages for, for example, www.youtube.com, or gemini.google.com
So I would conclude that this IP can serve requests for a number of different hostnames, and that it may not be possible to pin down precisely which service this IP address was working on behalf of.

It's not particularly pleasant, fast or efficient, but one can request to download a list of all domains on gTLDs from https://czds.icann.org/ and run a DNS query on each and every one. I know people that did this before.
Of course you'll have to also maintain a list of potential subdomains. If this IP address is only used on a subdomain that you're not checking for, or only on a ccTLD, or not used as an (A) DNS record at all, then you're not going to find anything.
nmap can reveal also what other records you might want to look at (e.g. if you see a mail server running, you can check MX records), though in this case there's only 80 and 443.
